# When the elements of given classes are not present in the small DOM checking their invisibility takes very long time

Tags: c#, .net, performance, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Before I click any link, I make sure that there are no loader spinners visible in the page anywhere. For some reason it takes up to 40 seconds on the page where there are no spinners at all, on all other it's flash fast.

To be sure that there are no spinners I wrote this method:

```
    public static void WaitForSpinnersToDisappear(this IWebDriver driver)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        wait.Until(InvisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
            By.ClassName("spinnertype1"),
            By.ClassName("spinnertype2"),
            By.ClassName("spinnertype3")));
    }
```

which utilizes this function:

```
    public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> InvisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(params By[] locators)
    {
        return driver =>
        {

            return locators.All(locator =>
            {
                var elements = driver.FindElements(locator); //this is incredibly slow
                if (elements.Count == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return driver.FindElements(locator).All(element => !element.Displayed);
            });
        };
    }
```

for some reason  `var elements = driver.FindElements(locator);` invoked in`InvisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` function is incredibly slow only for the server generated page with short DOM where are no spinners at all.

Comment: not sure why you're re-writing the expected condition there, but you might consider using the webdriver wait to wait for the next Selenium action.  That's what they're designed for.  If the timeout is reached, then you may have a script that is taking too long to do it's job and it should be written up.  Also, if you can interact with an item that should not be active at that point it should also be written up.

Comment: My guess is that you have an implicit wait set somewhere to a high value. The Selenium docs state not to mix implicit and explicit waits because of issues like this. You should remove implicit waits and add explicit waits when needed.

Comment: @Yoda Incredibly you are reinventing the same wheel called _ExpectedConditions_ which not only induces extra instruction cycles but also increases the execution time multi-fold.

Comment: @pcalkins But there is no expected condition for invisibility of all elements only for a single element.

Comment: @DebanjanB There is no invisibility of all given elements condition available from the get go. `FindElements` is called only 3 times, once for each class passed, but it takes very long time to execute.

Comment: @Yoda of coarse there are a couple of [`InvisibilityOfElementLocated()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_InvisibilityOfElementLocated.htm) and [`InvisibilityOfElementWithText()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_InvisibilityOfElementWithText.htm)

Comment: @DebanjanB elementS, plural.

Comment: @Yoda Exactly that's what I am trying to convey, `spinnertype1`, `spinnertype2` and `spinnertype3` won't happen together during page load or for any action on a single element. They would appear for different elements. That's why by all possible means `WaitForSpinnersToDisappear()` is pure **overhead**.

Comment: there is: https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfAllElements-java.util.List-  But that may not be what you need.  You'd find all the elements, and then the wait would wait for them to be set as not visible (display css).  If they aren't there to begin with you'd need another approach.

Comment: Post the script(s) that launch the spinners so we can take a look at what they are doing.  Some will create the element and inject it into the DOM... some will rely on the element already being there and just change or remove a style attribute.